# Multiple application with one authentication in spring security

Tags: java, spring, security

I want to create one authentication link, like `account.envato.com` and multiple applications will be automatically authenticated by same username and password. How can I implement this?

Comment: Today you would probably do this using an OAuth2 or Keycloak authentication server. The user would go to the authentication server and login, and the application would get back a token modeling the user authorization, this token can then be used to authentication with the service backend. If you use JWK services can validate the token without any callbacks to the authentication server, which is great for availability.